# MassIndexer.createIndexer() freezes when indexing multiple entity types

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

For the purposes of this question I have two business classes:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class MyClassOne implements MyInterface {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<MyClassTwo> myClassTwos;

    @Field
    private String someField;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class MyClassTwo implements MyInterface {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @Field
    private String someField;
}
```

I then use the following code to create the index (as suggested in the Hibernate Search docs):

```
Search.getFullTextSession(session).createIndexer(MyClassOne.class, MyClassTwo.class).startAndWait();
```

The problem is, this freezes. MassIndexer.createIndexer() hangs indefinitely and I don't get anywhere.

If I remove either of the Class arguments then the remaining class is indexed and everything works perfectly - it is just a problem when I try to index the two entities at the same time. My understanding is that hibernate creates a separate index per entity by default, I certainly haven't done any configuration to change this.

For clarity I have removed the @AnalyzerDef, @Boost annotations and the @Field and @Indexed annotation parameters, but removing these makes no difference to the underlying problem. I left in the fact that both classes implement the same interface, and that one contains a List of the other (although note that this is not @IndexEmbedded) in case it is relevant.

(also I found a thread suggesting that thread pool size is a problem so I increased it to 50 but no luck)

Presumably I'm doing something obvious wrong but I'm out of ideas - can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It might seem to freeze when it runs out of database connections; it effectively deadlocks relying on connection timeout from the database pool library to "get free".

Instead of increasing the thread pool, you should lower it so as not to exhaust your connections; each thread is going to use one. Alternatively, if you can it's more effective to raise the maximum amount of allowed connections to the database.

I've opened a JIRA issue to address this by detecting it somehow, worst case document it better.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and indexing entities one by one helped.

```
fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer(MyClassOne.class).startAndWait();
fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer(MyClassTwo.class).startAndWait();
```